# OperationCanceledException: Read was canceled on underlying PipeReader

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, .net-6.0

am getting this type of error while moving to NET 6.0

Grpc.Core.RpcException : Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Exception was thrown by handler. OperationCanceledException: Read was canceled on underlying PipeReader.")

package: Google.Protobuf v (3.21.12)
NET 6.0

I tried different solution while downgrading the version of the package
but still facing the same issue

Comment: clarification: are you actually using protobuf-net (tags), or are you using Google.Protobuf ("package")? (because those are two different implementations of protobuf)

Comment: what is the context here? is this client or server? and *which transport implementation* - for example, for the client there is `Grpc.Core` (google's unmanaged transport) and `Grpc.Net.Client` (Microsoft's managed transport); ditto at the server there are two; also: any code we can see related to this exception?

Comment: oh ya am using Google.Protobuf and the client is Grpc.Core

Comment: after moving to NET 6.0 an getting this type of error

Comment: To NET 6.0 but from what? if you're moving from .NET Framework 4.something, for example, then yes: I'd absolutely expect pain. You say you're using `Grpc.Core` - that contains both client and server parts, so: which are you using here? again, can we see code? When moving the .NET 6.0, the best advice is to move from the *unmanaged* transport (`Grpc.Core`) to the relevant (client vs server) *managed* transport; this is usually pretty simple - for client-side code it means using `GrpcChannel.ForAddress(...)` instead of `new Channel(...)`, *and that's all*. Happy to advise more, but: context!

Comment: more detail

 at Google.Protobuf.WritingPrimitivesMessages.WriteRawMessage(WriteContext& ctx, IMessage message)
   at Google.Protobuf.WritingPrimitivesMessages.WriteMessage(WriteContext& ctx, IMessage value)
   at Google.Protobuf.WriteContext.WriteMessage(IMessage value)

Comment: doesn't provide the generated method that enables WriteContext-based serialization. You might need to regenerate the generated protobuf code.

Comment: am calling the grpc getAll endpoint from the test while creating the chennal using GrpcChannel.ForAddress this

Answer (score 1):

> Message SOMETHING doesn't provide the generated method that enables WriteContext-based serialization. You might need to regenerate the generated protobuf code.

This comes [from here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/ParsingPrimitivesMessages.cs#L253)

The problem here is that you're using (significantly) older generated code which does not support the pipe APIs; you should regenerate the code from the .proto, after updating `protoc` or `Grpc.Tools` or whatever mechanism you've used to turn the .proto schema into C#. This must include any nested message types; the `SOMETHING` in the above message tells you about any that are still needed.

Comment: regenerated the proto file using proto compiler still facing the same

Comment: @Bill ok; what is the SOMETHING in your message? Where is that SOMETHING defined? is it in your code, or some shared code? Can we see the code for that SOMETHING? (in particular, IIRC the file tells you which version of the tooling it was generated from)

Comment: some thing its a proto buf message

Comment: @Bill yes, I know that; you're having an issue with a **specific** message; to help you, I need visibility of *that specific message*. Without that, there's nothing I can do or say - except maybe ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. So: to help you, *I need that information*. For context, I'm the author of protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc, work on the Microsoft team that looks after the Microsoft side of Grpc, and am on the Grpc core team. Happy to talk via email or something if this is a public visibility thing (i.e. you don't want to share the message details on Stack Overflow / GitHub)

Comment: message PageParameters {
 string term = 1;
 int32  skip = 2;
 int32  top = 3;
}

Comment: here is the code snippnet

Comment: message GetAllDepartmentQuery {
 PageParameters page_parameters = 1;
}

Comment: @Bill that's the .proto schema; what we're interested in is the generated C# code; it'll start with `// <auto-generated>` and `//     Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!` and probably have `public sealed partial class GetAllDepartmentQuery : pb::IMessage<GetAllDepartmentQuery>`; but in particular what's interesting is whether it implements `IBufferMessage` - I'll see if I can find what protoc version started emitting that - also check whether you have the `GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_REFSTRUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` symbol defined, which disables that feature

Comment: @Bill looks like it was released Aug 15 2020 in v3.13.0 - check whether you're using tooling (in particular `protoc`) more recent than that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250836/discussion-between-bill-and-marc-gravell).